# How to add column menu to primeNG datatable to show and hide columns

Tags: angular, angular-ui-grid, primeng, primeng-datatable

We are upgrading our angularJS project to angular 4 and are using the primeNG components including the primeNG datatable. Does anyone know how to create a hide/show menu item the same way the angular-ui-grid has to hide/show columns?

[image]

We figured we can use the [hidden] property in the html `<p-column field="somefield" [hidden]="!isColumnVisible"` but the customer also wants a visual menu with a drop down item they can easily check/uncheck which columns to hide the same was the angular-ui-grid does.

Comment: You can override header template and add the hamburger icon with a menu.

Comment: try this https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/coltoggler

Comment: Thanks. These two comments helped.